# Php array from sql result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How can i create an array from the result? I would like to use the array in a mysql IN() query.

```
//$array = array();
        $get_subscategoria = mysqli_query($kapcs, "SELECT kat_id FROM termek_kategoria WHERE kat_parent = '$id'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($get_subscategoria) > 0 )
        {
            while($sub_kat = mysqli_fetch_array($get_subscategoria))
            {
                echo $sub_kat['kat_id'];
                //$array[] = $sub_kat;
            }
        }
        //print_r( $array );
```

Now, this code gives back 4 row ID, that works okay. I would like an array with these ID-s, like 1,2,3,4.

Comment: use prepared statements

Comment: do you need an array or a string?

Comment: I want to use it in a mysqli query, with an IN() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($sub_kat = mysqli_fetch_array($get_subscategoria))
{
$array[] = $sub_kat['kat_id'];
}
echo implode(",",$array);
```

it give a result like 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
while($sub_kat = mysqli_fetch_array($get_subscategoria))
{
    echo $sub_kat['kat_id'];
    //$array[] = $sub_kat;
}
```

use:

```
$array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_subscategoria);
```

Answer (score 1):

For `MySQL`, also you can use `group_concat`, only gives you one record:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(kat_id) AS kat_id
FROM termek_kategoria 
WHERE kat_parent = '$id'
GROUP BY kat_parent
```

Comment: It gives Undefined index: kat_id error. But the name in the table is kat_id, thats correct.

Comment: @Dave599 Then use `kat_id` as alias, check it again.