# How can I get array values from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a SQL table and the name is 'table1' and table structure is below.

```
ID|customer_name|orders_id|
---------------------------
1 |  muko       |   1     |
2 |  luma       |   2     |
3 |  muko       |   2     |
4 |  ceki       |   8     |
5 |  ceki       |   10    |
6 |  muko       |   7     |
7 |  luma       |   11    |
---------------------------
```

etc...

How can I output them as array  like this in PHP:

```
$customers = array ("muko"=>[1,2,7], "luma"=>[2,11], "ceki"=>[8,10] );
```

Comment: we can use **"customer_ID"** instead of **"customer_name"**

Comment: check this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434334/php-array-from-sql-result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434334/php-array-from-sql-result)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use group by clause to get the result:

```
SELECT customer_name, orders_id = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + orders_id
           FROM table1 b 
           WHERE b.customer_name = a.customer_name 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM table1 a
GROUP BY customer_name
```

Answer (score 2):

E.g.:

```
<?php

/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a;

CREATE TABLE table_a
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,customer_name VARCHAR(12)
,order_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table_a VALUES
(1,'muko',1),
(2,'luma',2),
(3,'muko',2),
(4,'ceki',8),
(5,'ceki',10),
(6,'muko',7),
(7,'luma',11);

*/

require('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "
SELECT a.id
     , a.customer_name
     , a.order_id
  FROM table_a a
 ORDER
    BY a.customer_name
     , a.order_id;
";

$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);

$old_array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $old_array[] = $row;
}

$new_array = array();

foreach ($old_array as $row) {
   $new_array['customer_name'][$row['customer_name']][] = $row['order_id'];
}

$new_array = array_values($new_array); // reindex


print_r($new_array);

?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ceki] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8
                    [1] => 10
                )

            [luma] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 11
                )

            [muko] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 7
                )

        )

)
```